# Storing a staff hierarchy in active directory e.g. staff > manager relationships

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

Is it possible to store user (and therefore use in e.g. asp.net) a staff hierarchy in active directory e.g. staff > manager relationships.

My active directory install is relatively flexible, so I could add additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to [extend the AD schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759633.aspx) to support what you want to do, but I would seriously consider why you want to do it, and how many changes you might make down the road (not to mention how unhappy your system administrator might be after these changes).

The presence of AD is not a prerequisite to using built-in Asp.net authentication methods (although it makes integrated authentication much easier).  If this kind of data is application specific, I would recommend looking into maintaining the data in an application-specific database.  In doing so, you could pull the current user's FQDN from the `HttpContext.Current.User`, and key on the `Name` property of the associated `Identity`.  For example:
`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

From that point, you simply create a `UserProfile` table with associated organizational structures (i.e. a column for `ReportsTo` that acts as a reference to another `UserProfile`.